# Testing kafka listener with Spring boot with a custom factory

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, testing

I'm having a real hard time trying to test a Kafka listener with a custom container factory. An important fact here is that the test is working perfectly if I simply remove the containerFactory parameter from the annotation. When the containerFactory parameter is present, the message is never received by the listener function.

According the logs the connection could not be stablished, seems the factory is not receiving the overrided property during the test.

```
 Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established.
```

The listener class :

```
@Component
class KafkaListener(
        private val useCase: UseCase
) {
    @KafkaListener(
            topics = ["topic"],
            groupId = "demo",
            containerFactory = "containerFactory",
            clientIdPrefix = "prefix"
    )
    fun listener(message: String) {
        println("message received!")
        useCase.foo()
    }
}
```

The test:

```
@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest(properties = ["spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest"])
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = [MongoAutoConfiguration::class])
@Import(KafkaListener::class)
class KafkaShippingGroupCreationListenerAdapterTest {

    companion object {
        @Container
        private val kafkaContainer = KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.3"))

        @JvmStatic
        @DynamicPropertySource
        fun overrideProperties(registry: DynamicPropertyRegistry) {
            registry.add("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers", kafkaContainer::getBootstrapServers);
        }
    }

    @MockBean
    private lateinit var useCase: UseCase

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var kafkaTemplate: KafkaTemplate<String, Any>

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var kafkaListener: KafkaListener

    @Test
    fun `should invoke the use case`() {
        kafkaTemplate.send("topic", "message")

        verify(useCase,
                timeout(5000).times(1)).foo()
    }
}
```

The factory:

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
class Config {
    fun customFactory(): ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> {
        val factory = ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>()
        factory.consumerFactory = consumerFactory()

        return factory
    }

    @Bean
    fun containerFactory(): ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> = customFactory()
}
```

Any clues on how to update the factory according the port given by the container?

I'm using springboot **2.3.10.RELEASE**